# Automatically generate diagram based on respondent's answers in Google Forms

Tags: google-forms

I have a questionnaire in Google Forms, where respondent answers some questions about his physical shape. All answers are taken in numbers.

My goal is to interactively generate a visualization diagram, based only on the individual respondent's answers, and give an opportunity to download it as an image or save it somehow.

Ideally, I see it in a way, that after submitting in Google Forms, an image with the diagram is shown and a link for downloading this image. Also, a button for sharing in social media is desirable.

Please, give me an idea, how it can be implemented? Which instruments I should use? Maybe Google Forms are not perfectly suitable for such a task?